# Resize Magento media Image

Tags: magento-1.9, image

I am looking for a solution to resize a content image, coming from `media/wysiwyg/` within the output template of a widget.

Is there anything or have the content editors to do that by photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resize your catalog images but not your wysiwyg media images, this is up to the content admin.

Comment: Can't I use the magento resize function some way for that?